# xmpp openfire server offer reject not working

Tags: xmpp, chat, openfire, strophe

I am working on a chat application and using Fastpath plugin of Openfire Chat server for workgroups and queues.

When a user is sending a chat invitation/offer to workgroup it is going to all the agents available in the workgroup, on round robin fashion. when the one of agents accepts chat invitation/offer I am sending following info query to server which works fine because once the agent accept chat invitation/offer same offer don't goes to other users.

this is the info query string :-

```xml
<iq to="test-home@workgroup.domain" id="833-197" type="set" xmlns="jabber:client">
    <offer-accept jid="sender@workgroup.domain" id="offerId" xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/workgroup">
    </offer-accept>
</iq>
```

but when agent rejects the offer I am sending following info query, which is not working, and the same user is getting  invitation/offer again and again

```xml
<iq to="test-home@workgroup.domain" id="833-197" type="set" xmlns="jabber:client">
    <offer-reject jid="sender@workgroup.domain" id="offerId" xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/workgroup">
    </offer-reject>
</iq>
```

Comment: AFAIK, rejecting the offer is valid for that offer request only. New offer request will be sent again on next round robin.

Comment: If this is the case then it works fine, is there any way I can force server to do not send offer once rejected by a user.